# Why I got Not Found error when request a text file

Tags: .htaccess

When I request the file `https://www.hello.com.au/myfile.txt`
I got an error  "Not Found. The requested URL `https://www.hello.com.au/myfile.txt` was not found on this server."

Here's my .htaccess rule, which is working fine on my dev site, but not working on Production.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?hello\.com\.au$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^myfile\.txt$ - [NC,F]  
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Does the `.txt` file exist in your filesystem?

Comment: Your RewriteCond does not match, because the request hostname _is_ `www.hello.com.au`, so the following RewriteRule does not apply to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I found, the file myfile.txt doesn't exists in Production.  Thanks everyone for your help.